# SQLite Error 1 No Column SQLite Insert Error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a SQLite database within my app, exporting it to the sd card. I am getting the error

> 01-13 12:31:39.621: I/Database(3828): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table inventory has no column named location
>
> SQLite insert error

Here is my code for creating the database...I can't seem to find the problem.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE inventory ("
                + "_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "serialnum TEXT,"
                + "modelnum TEXT," + "manufact TEXT," + "description TEXT,"
                + "time DATETIME" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            Log.d("SW","Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE inventory ADD location TEXT");
        }
        if (oldVersion < 3) {
            Log.d("SW","Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE inventory ADD other TEXT");
        }

    }
```

Comment: By the way the opensource project I am working off of is http://code.google.com/p/simplescan/source/checkout Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax for adding new column:

[ALTER TABLE test1 ADD COLUMN foo;](http://www.devdaily.com/android/sqlite-alter-table-syntax-examples)

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        Log.d("SW","Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE inventory ADD COLUMN location TEXT");
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
        Log.d("SW","Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE inventory ADD COLUMN other TEXT");
    }

}
```

Comment: Tried that, not working. Check out the link in my comment for the opensource data I am working off of. thanks

Comment: This is answer is correct in that this IS how you correctly add a column. My problem was stemming from improperly adding a spinner that created the data for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER TABLE inventory ADD COLUMN location TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first SQL command to:

```
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE inventory ("
            + "_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + "serialnum TEXT,"
            + "modelnum TEXT," + "manufact TEXT," + "description TEXT,"
            + "time DATETIME," + "location TEXT" + ");");
```

- your create table statement didn't include the location column.